# How can I support the murder-plot of another character?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Thanks to my spymaster I recently found out that there is a conspiracy of nefarious plotters among my vassals who plan the murder of my beloved son. As a ruler and father I am outraged by their insolence... that they didn't ask for my help!

I think murdering him is a great idea! I was looking for ways to decimate my offsprings for years (damn gravelkind succession, damn lustful + midas touched wife), and these guys are doing it for me without me risking to get my hands dirty. So I would like to do everything in my power to have them succeed.

Is there anything I can do to help them? Can I somehow get them to invite *me* to their plot, encourage others to support the plot or boost the plot power of those already involved?

Comment: Now only imagine if the title said : "How can i support the murder-plot on my son".

Comment: I have the exact same scenario, so will be interested to what answers arise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Even if you find out about a plot, you can only join it if you're invited. Inviting you is based around whether you would accept if you were an AI and it may actually be impossible for a character to be invited to murder their child. Even if it wasn't, you'd have to somehow deal with your +50 opinion of your son.

If your son is still in your court, you could try increasing the potential power by finding more potential plotters and inviting them to your court. Fill your court with people who hate your and/or like the plot leader, ideally with decent intrigue, and you'll soon find them involved too. Check if your son has any rivals- that'd be a good place to start.

Comment: Also consider your Spymaster. The more skilled he is, the harder assassinating your son will be, as your son is shielded by your realm's Intrigue score. Unless of course, your Spymaster also wants your son dead. On that note, either install a Spymaster that dislikes your son (enough to kill him), or try having no Spymaster at all (Warning, this could get a number of non-target characters assassinated). A somewhat situational option is taking a new wife with a high Intrigue score and hoping she tries to help thin your previous wife's gene pool.

Comment: Also, if he is unlanded and underage, you could make the plot leader his guardian! ;D Assumingly, that increases the plot power.

Comment: This answer is starting to feel like a plot. I'm going to tell everyone about it.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not a direct answer to your original question but if your overall goal is to kill  your son and current heir and he has a low intrigue value you could try making him your spy master and then send him off to steal tech. Especially the tech of some ruler with a high intrigue spy master. He'll eventually be caught and likely killed unless you're really unlucky.

Actually just making him your spy master in general will likely shorten his life span considerably.

Comment: The Byzantine Empire do love to castrate their prisoners...