# My son is a moron and I don't want him inheriting my empire. Why can't I nominate him as a bishop?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

This is my firstborn son, Enrique.  He's a total moron. Unfortunately, he's also my heir.  (I have primogeniture succession and papal investiture.)

[image: 3 diplomacy?? Seriously.]

My usual plan would be to nominate him for a Bishopric via the Pope.  The Pope adores me (92 opinion).  Sadly, Enrique doesn't show up under the list of people I can nominate.  He's definitely at my court, and he doesn't own any land.

[image: Please take him, Pope Telesphorus! Please!!]

Why can't I nominate my son for a Bishopric?

Comment: I think this exploit has been removed, so that you cannot forcefully remove your heirs from the line of succession. I think you need to consider the sturdiness of your balconies.

Comment: Oh ... That's a shame! :( but I can't assassinate my own sons, either - what are my other options for getting rid of him?

Comment: You can't plot against your offspring? Are you sure? If that truly is the case, you might consider him to spearhead 300 men in battle against a million foes. Risky though, they might simply put him in jail, and you'll be put under regency. He is strong, and thus less likely to die.

Comment: Yep, sadly!  http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?674154-Why-can-t-I-murder-my-own-son

I can imprison and execute him though, which I'm now thinking is my only option.

Comment: I saw this on Hot Questions and initially thought it was from the parenting stackexchange....

Comment: This might also be helpful: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199706/how-can-i-support-the-murder-plot-of-another-character

Comment: By the way, to avoid this in the future, always tutor your heir yourself. This will give you popup events to decide which traits you want them to have. This is usually much more valuable than the stats they would inherit from someone with better stats than you. Just before they turn 16, give them to someone who has an education trait you want them to have, because the education trait is influenced solely by the tutor they have the moment they become adult.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Craven, Slothful, Gluttonous, Content AND a lowest-rank education trait. I can scarcely imagine a worse heir without adding bad congenital traits...

Your heir cannot be intentionally removed from the line of succession by making him a bishop. As you have discovered you cannot plot against your offspring without Mods. Such mods DO exist though, so there's that.

Without Mods, there are a few dangerous councilor missions that could get him killed. I have often heard that using a Spymaster to steal technology from powerful rulers is principally a good way to get a dead Spymaster. Sending a Chaplain to convert Pagans will usually get them thrown in jail, which could easily lead to an early grave.

If you haven't changed your succession laws during the current Emperor's reign the guaranteed fix is to change the laws. From your screenshot, Ultimogeniture would give the kingdom to a younger brother who is yet a child, but a child ruler might still be better than Enrique the Idiot. Elective would give you the option to let you and your vassals choose your heir, surely somewhere in your family there is someone more fit to rule than Enrique the Idiot.

As a last gasp effort (due to the considerable costs) you can likely imprison and execute him, but that way lies some SEVERE penalties, a sizable amount of tyrrany penalty and Kinslayer Trait besides.

Comment: I'm glad I have your sympathies.  What's really annoying is that my other sons are pretty awesome.

I unfortunately have already upped my Crown Authority so can't change another Crown Law, but I did find another potential way out (albeit a slow payoff) - I took the Intrigue focus and spied on him, hoping I can kill him that way.  I'll give it a few years and if not, I'll risk the Kinslayer / Tyranny.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good answer – but bear in mind, that Enrique is Strong. That gives him a health boost, and he is less likely to die in prison (or just in general). Him in prison is a really good way to get shafted with a regent for sixty years! On the other hand he is also a coward, which makes it less likely for him to be captured or killed. Man, Enrique relly sucks.

Comment: To be fair to Enrique though, several of those negative traits are reversible through events like feasts and hunts.

Comment: Oh, spy on is a good way to go. I've once disinherited someone by discovering they were a bastard with the spy on action.